# global name 'reqparse' is not defined

Tags: python, api, rest

I am trying to develop an API in python to create user. Below is my code.

```
   from flask import Flask
   from flask_restful import Resource, Api
   app = Flask(__name__)
   api = Api(app)

   class CreateUser(Resource):
       def post(self):
          try:
            # Parse the arguments
              parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
              parser.add_argument('email', type=str, help='Email address to create user')
              parser.add_argument('password', type=str, help='Password to create user') 
              args = parser.parse_args()
              _userEmail = args['email']
              _userPassword = args['password']
              return {'Email': args['email'], 'Password': args['password']}

          except Exception as e:
              return {'error': str(e)}
   api.add_resource(CreateUser, '/CreateUser')
   if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)
```

However when I run it on my REST client, I post the email and password in JSON format to the client as 
      {
         "Email" : "abc@xyz.com" ,
         "Password" : "abc"
      }

I get an error in the REST client body as 
**{
        "error": "global name 'reqparse' is not defined"
}**

I have Python 2.7 64bit with the flask-restful and all flask libraries installed. Can someone tell me the fix ???

Comment: You're not importing `reqparse`.

Comment: Thanks I did that :) and now i get null for both email and password whereas I should but getting what I posted. Can you tell me what am I missing

Answer (score 0):

You will want to instantiate your parser and add the arguments before your request handler. I mean move

```
# Parse the arguments
  parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
  parser.add_argument('email', type=str, help='Email address to create user')
  parser.add_argument('password', type=str, help='Password to create user')
```

to the line after `api = Api(app)`

Comment: i still get email and password both as null in response body

Comment: Do you mean in the request body?

Comment: No in the response body

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments of your post, you need to import reqparse:

```
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse
```

And for your other problem of null received, you need to be careful to the case.
If you send: `{ "Email" : "abc@xyz.com" , "Password" : "abc" }`, your python code needs to be like that:

```
parser.add_argument('Email', type=str, help='Email address to create user')
parser.add_argument('Password', type=str, help='Password to create user')
```

(sorry I can not directly respond in the comments, I don't have enough reputation)

Comment: Tried the same but the null for email and password still pertains